# What's this thing on my scattergun?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Here is a screenshot of my Scout loadout:

[image]

Inside the red circle there's a very small icon that appears to be some sort of counter. I have a 1080p screen and it's so small that I can't read the text. What is it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is a [Strange Weapon](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Strange) which has a kill-count, you can tell because it is called rage-inducing.

You have not seen this before because the [update](http://www.teamfortress.com/post.php?id=18182) yesterday (August 27, 2015)
made the following change

```
> All Strange items now have a visible icon in backpack panels
```

Answer (score 5):

The icon you're asking about is used on skins from Gun Mettle to indicate that the weapon is Strange. As of the [August 27, 2015 patch](http://www.teamfortress.com/post.php?id=18182), the icon has now been added to *all* Strange items in the backpack view.

**As you can see here, it also appears on mine:**

[image: Scout loadout (icons visible)]

Contrary to Jeeva's comment (which has since been deleted), the icon does not indicate that the weapon has a Strange part. None of the weapons I have equipped for the Scout have a Strange Part added to them.

**The icon also appears to be static**; the counter shown on it won't actually update in relation to the current stats on it and will remain at *000000*.

Comment: The downvote suggests this answer is incorrect. Downvoter, could you tell me what's wrong by adding your own answer?

Comment: Gun Mettle skins use a slightly different icon.  Specifically, the color is different (orange as opposed to normal Stranges which have a blue icon).  I can't read the text, but it also appears to be different.

Comment: @Powerlord I wouldn't think it says anything other than 000000, but you would be right about the colour.